# How regex engine works for "[*=]+$"

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build regex  that removes `*` and `=` or any combination of them from the **end** of the string, so I tried  `"[*=]$"`, but it was lazy, for example, if I have the string `this is a dog =*`, then it will remove `*` and keep `=`, then I tried the regex `[*=]+$`, and it did the job, But I can't understand how the regex engine would work with the last regex, or in another word, how this regex become greedy.

Comment: NOte that `+` repeats the previous token one or more times. So `[*=]+` matches one or more `*` or `=` symbols exists at the last.

Comment: use https://regex101.com/ if you want to try regex, or any other regex tester

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `+` repeats the previous token one or more times. So `[*=]+` matches one or more `*` or `=` symbols exists at the last.

What happens in the background is, at first `[*=]` matches all the `*` or `=` symbols (*matching continuous characters*). Once after regex engine saw the `+` which exists next to the char class, then it starts to match the following `*` or `=` symbols. And finally once it saw the end of the line anchor `$`, all the matches other than the one exists at the last will get discarded by the regex engine. Now, you left with the last match (*match exists at the end of a line*).